# Deploy the WordPress localhost database to live server

Tags: database, wordpress, git, deployment

I need some help as getting out of the idea, I have set up a WordPress with git and everything works fine, deploying that with the https://deployhq.com to push changes automatically to the live server.

But was wondering if there's any way to push the database as well along with when pushing changes to the master branch. It just pushes the WordPress files but not the database.

Thoughts?

Comment: "It just pushes the WordPress files but not the database"—yep, that's how it works. Application state (e.g. databases, uploaded files) isn't tracked by Git, and merging databases is super tricky (I _strongly_ recommend against it). If you want to do a one-time deploy of your database you can do so using regular MySQL tools or a WordPress import / export plugin.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. With files everything works fine like a charm but moving the database with a plugin or manually with search and replace of URLs is a kinda annoying was wondering if there's any 3rd party as well that could automate this task as well?

Comment: You're missing my point. It's a _good_ thing that Git doesn't sync application state. Your development database _should_ be different from your production one. Doing it occasionally might be okay, but this definitely shouldn't be part of your regular workflow.

Comment: Ok. Got it then that's it already. Thanks for the input. :)

Comment: Hello @Abd Ur Rehman do you have any update on this? Is there a solution?

Comment: @Szelek check the thread comments from Chris. That makes sense.

Comment: @Abd Ur Retman, i was able to solve this by using Migrate DB WP plugin, thanks.